# 3D transformations for pseudo-elements

Tags: css, google-chrome, pseudo-element

Does someone knows why Google Chrome browser does not supports 3d transformations for pseudo-elements (::before and ::after)?

**EDIT** Google Chrome 13.0.782.55 beta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of bugs surrounding pseudo elements. I'd file a bug, and produce a test case in jsfiddle to attach to it.

Comment: I’ve submitted a bug to Chrome issue tracker a cople of days ago ([issue 88459](http://goo.gl/dpZZj)) but it wasn’t assigned to anyone yet. So I thought I should ask here just in case it’s not actually a bug (feedback in so is blazing fast). Thanks, Rich. Now, after I looked closely to issues related to pseudo-elements in Chrome, things are much more clear to me now.